# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I am new to Android Development.

I am trying to fetch the db values based on userid in a list view using JSON.

I searched stackoverflow for this problem, But I can't able to find a soln for this.

I don't know what I am getting, JSONArray or JSONObject.

The title was shown in the logcat. I have tried the below mentioned code.

```
public class Search_Id extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static String url_search_by_id="php file in the remote server";

    private static final String REGISTER="regs";
    private static final String ID="id";
    private static final String FNAME="fname";
    private static final String LNAME="lname";
    private static final String PROFILEFOR="profilefor";
    private static final String AGE="age";

    private ProgressDialog PDialog;
    EditText Et_sear_id;    
    Button Btn_Search;

    TextView  search_id_detail_id,search_id_detail_fname,search_id_detail_lname,search_id_detail_profilefor,search_id_detail_age;

public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_id);
    Et_sear_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sear_et_id);
    Btn_Search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sear_btn_search);
    Btn_Search.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(Btn_Search))
    {
    //new SearchDetail().execute();
    final String st_id=Et_sear_id.getText().toString();

    if(st_id.length()>0)
    {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameter=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postparameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",st_id));

        String response=null;
        try
        {
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("php file in the remote      server", postparameter);  
            String res=response.toString();
            //  res = res.trim();
            res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            //error.setText(res);


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(res.equals("yes"))
            {   
                new SearchDetail().execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Et_sear_id.setText("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Et_sear_id.setError("Provide ID to Search");
    }

    }
}

class SearchDetail extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    //final String St_sear_id1=Et_sear_id.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PDialog=new ProgressDialog(Search_Id.this);
        PDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        PDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        PDialog.setCancelable(true);
        PDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        final String st_id=Et_sear_id.getText().toString();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();          
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",st_id));

        JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_by_id_guna,"POST",params);

        //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comes into Try Block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONArray jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(REGISTER);

            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jo=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                int id   = jo.getInt(ID);
                String fname = jo.getString(FNAME);
                String lname= jo.getString(LNAME);
                String profile_for=jo.getString(PROFILEFOR);
                String age=jo.getString(AGE);

                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Search_Id_Detail.class);
                //i.putExtra("REGISTER", regs);
                in.putExtra("ID",id);
                in.putExtra("FNAME",fname);
                in.putExtra("LNAME",lname);
                in.putExtra("PROFILEFOR",profile_for);
                in.putExtra("AGE",age);
                startActivity(in);          
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String arg)
    {
        PDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

PHP File is following:

```
<?php

     /* Following code will list all products */

     //array for JSON response
     $response=array();

     $id=$_POST['id'];

     require_once 'vivagha_db_connect.php';
     //Connect to database
     $db=new DB_CONNECT();

     //get all products from products table
     $result=mysql_query("select *from regs where db_reg_id=$id") or die(mysql_error());

     //check for empty result
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
          //looping through all results
          //products node
          //$response["regs"]=array();

          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
             //temp user array
             //$register=array();
             $response["id"]=$row["db_reg_id"];
             $response["fname"]=$row["db_reg_fname"];
             $response["lname"]=$row["db_reg_lname"];
             $response["profilefor"]=$row["db_reg_profilefor"];
             $response["age"]=$row["db_reg_age"];

             //push single product into final response array
             //array_push($response["regs"],$register);
             $response["success"]=1;
             $response["message"]="Found";
        }

        //success
        //response["success"]=1;

        //echo JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
     }
     else
     {
        //no product found
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="No Products Found";

         //echo no users JSON   
         //echo json_encode($response);
     }
    //} 
    ?>
```

I entered the user's id, then If the id is available in the user's details must be shown. But It gives me the log as the title suggests.

It would be helpful for me to learn android, If I can get a solution for this.

Comment: seems like your incoming response is not a valid JSON string

Comment: response is not JSON type. what the number of line the exception is generated? can you display the contents of the log response. (can be a simple error connecting to server)

Comment: @julien dumortier - W/System.err(1317):  at com.example.vivagha.Search_Id_guna$SearchDetail.doInBackground(Search_Id_guna.java:151) this is what shows in the log file.

Comment: as said @Budius I also think you can not communicate with the server. It should display the text returned by the query. In this response, we expect to see a message like:
'<! DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "- / / IETF / / DTD HTML 2.0 / / EN">
<html> <head>
<title> 404 Not Found </ title>
</ head> <body>
<h1> Not Found </ h1> "

so that we can confirm that this is an error connecting to the server

Comment: @juliendumortier - I got error while executing the PHP file. I will make right changes to the PHP file. If error continues, I will post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I can see the problem is that you're getting the actual php file and not the result from the processing of such file.

The problem actually have NOTHING to do with android. Try typing the same address on your web-browser and you'll see this same PHP file you posted for us.

You need to configure a server to process that PHP file and return the JSON response.

Comment: For some reasons, I didn't give the server details.

Comment: @juliendumortier: I executed the PHP file and it gives me - {"id":"4","fname":"Gunaseelan","lname":"Guna","profilefor":"Self","age":"0","success":1,"message":"Found"}. But I can't able to display the result. It shows no values

Comment: @guna seelan I m getting same error in another application

Comment: @NitinKarale The result is coming as a type of java.lang.String. Where we are trying to convert it into JSONObject. This is the problem.

Comment: @gunaseelan In PHP file getting result correct. It was working fine. But suddenly all files getting errors means for login & register user.It is getting error Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE HTML of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject